# Colours disappear when I use my .bashrc

Tags: bash, bashrc

Of late I've started using bash extensively so I decided that I'd be better off with a `.bashrc`. I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Here is my [`.bashrc`](https://github.com/abhirathmahipal/dotfiles/commit/aa4d6a1cb728b75c1e553e923b126429f152d288). It hardly has anything in it. Nothing even remotely related to colour.

```
function most_active_files_git {
     # https://stackoverflow.com/a/7686616/5698202
     git log --pretty=format: --name-only | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg
}

function sort_files_by_size_current_directory {
    ls -lShr
}

function find_main_function {
    grep -r -- 'main[  ]*(\|int main\|__main__\|main\s* ='
}
```

When I copy this file to `~/` and open up a new terminal, there's no colour. When I delete my `.bashrc` from `~/` and open up a new terminal the colours re-appear.

Coloured text given by Vim and Git work fine though. No colours appear when I `ls`, `grep` or use any of the system utilities.

**Things I've read and tried:-**

- `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` - I don't like this but it works. Is this the only way to get it to work?
- `force_color_prompt=yes` - Have tried putting this on top of my `.bashrc` as well. Doesn't work.
- Have tinkered with every setting in the menu bar. It shows that the colour setting haven't been touched at all. Yet they don't appear

Also why has such simple changes to the configuration resulted in something this unrelated?

Comment: "I'd be better off with a .bashrc" ... what happened to the `.bashrc` that came with Ubuntu?

Comment: You should have already had a default `~/.bashrc` file, that was copied from the /etc/skel directory when your user account was created. A better starting point IMHO would have been to modify that - rather than creating one from scratch (among other things, it provides color aliases for `ls` and `grep`)

Comment: @muru I restored the default one for now from the skel directory.

Comment: @steeldriver It works now. Thanks. Can you please answer it and I'll accept  your answer. Additionally am I at any disadvantage using it to build upon it? Most of the rc files on github use a clean configuration. Any particular reason?

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal Most people who tend to post their rc files online also are particular enough about their configuration that they don't want any of the stuff that comes by default. I, for example, am not (and my bashrc is mostly the default), but then I don't use bash (I use zsh instead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new `~/.bashrc` file overwrote a default one that was copied from the `/etc/skel` directory when the user account was created. Among many other things, that file provided the color prompt and aliases for `ls` and `grep`.

Instead of creating a new `~/.bashrc`, re-copy the default one and add your function definitions to that - or create a separate file for the functions and *source* it from the original `~/.bashrc`